# No puts or gets inside instance method - Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is really driving me up a wall.

I have an instance method I'm trying to debug, but I'm running into an issue where my puts and gets aren't showing up inside the instance method.

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

class Calculator
  def evaluate(string)
    ops = string.split(' ')
    ops.map! do |item|
      if item.is_a? Numeric
        return item.to_i
      else
        return item.to_sym
      end
    end

    puts "Got #{string}"         #Doesn't output
    puts "Converted to #{ops}"   #This too

    opscopy = ops.clone

    ops.each.with_index do |item, index|
      if item == :* || item == :/
        opscopy[index] = ops[index-1].send(item, ops[index+1])
        opscopy[index-1] = opscopy[index+1] = nil
      end
    end

    ops = opscopy.compact

    puts "After multi/div #{ops}"

    ops.each.with_index do |item, index|
      if item == :+ || item == :-
        opscopy[index] = ops[index-1].send(item, ops[index+1])
        opscopy[index-1] = opscopy[index+1] = nil
      end
    end

    puts "After +/- #{opscopy.compact}"

    opscopy.compact.first
  end
end

item = Calculator.new.evaluate "4 * 2"
puts "#{item} == 8"  #Prints :(
```

Output:

```
action@X:~/workspace/ruby$ ./calculator.rb                                                                                                                                                 
4 == 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `return` in your `map!` block is where the problem is.

```
ops.map! do |item|
  if item.is_a? Numeric
    return item.to_i # returns from method
  else
    return item.to_sym # returns from method
  end
end
```

You are returning the method in your `map!` block before the `puts` is called.

Change the `map!` block to:

```
ops.map! do |item|
  item.send(item.is_a?(Numeric) ? :to_i : :to_sym)
end
```

Comment: I'm a derp, thank you. I thought you could do that but I guess returning inside code blocks returns to the method closure.

Comment: Blocks and Procs return from the enclosing method, Methods and lambdas return from themselves. Also, blocks and Procs have loose argument checking, Methods and lambdas have strict argument checking. (Useful mnemonic: Blocks and Procs behave the same because they rhyme, Lambdas and Methods behave the same because they are both Greek.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag what do you mean by loose argument checking? Thanks for mnemonic! I